# Adding form post/submit button to javascript script

Tags: javascript, forms

I found this code on here (thanks to Xavi López) and it is ideal for what I need to add to my project but I'm in need of some help adding a Form post and submit button in JavaScript. I have no knowledge on this subject and I've tried looking at some example but non of them seem to work. I would be grateful if someone could help me. After the user adds the relevant number of input boxes and adds there data, I would like to have a submit button which will POST the results to another web page (result page)

I have added the solution to the below coding (thank you MTCoster) but I'm now try to find a solution to having the submit button appear only when an entry has been added. I have tried different methods but non will work.

```js
function addFields() {
  // Number of inputs to create
  var number = document.getElementById('member').value;
  
  // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  
  // Clear previous contents of the container
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    // Append a node with a random text
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Member ' + (i + 1) + ' '));
    
    // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    input.name = 'member' + i;
    container.appendChild(input);
    
    // Append a line break 
    container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of Pins: (max. 48)<br>
<a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Add Pinout Entries</a>
<form action="result.asp" method="POST">
<div id="container"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Add Data">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re almost there - all you need to do is wrap your inputs in a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element:

```js
function addFields() {
  // Number of inputs to create
  var number = document.getElementById('member').value;
  
  // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  
  // Clear previous contents of the container
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    // Append a node with a random text
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Member ' + (i + 1) + ' '));
    
    // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    input.name = 'member' + i;
    container.appendChild(input);
    
    // Append a line break 
    container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of Pins: (max. 48)<br>
<a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Add Pinout Entries</a>
<form action="/url/to/post/to" method="POST">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you’d like the submit button to only appear after at least one input is visible, you could add it at to `div#container` at the end of `addFields()`. I’ll leave this as an exercise to the OP, since it’s not much different to how you’re adding the input fields.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. Could you elaborate on how you would have it appear after one input has been selected, please

Comment: Try it yourself - as I said in the answer, it’s not much different to how you’re adding the other `<input>`s. It’ll work just fine added inside the `#container` rather than after it as I’ve put it.

Comment: Sorry I'm not to good on this. I'm trying to understand how to add it inside the #container If I try <form action="result.asp" method="POST"><div id="container"><input type="submit"></div> the submit button disappears when I add the entries.

Comment: Right, that’s why if you hardcode it it should be outside the `#container`. But if you’re dynamically adding it, ***do that the same way you’re adding the other inputs***

Comment: Would that mean the form submit button would need to been written in JavaScript so that when the user adds an entry it will only appear then?